# mysql select last entry for ids pair

Tags: mysql

I want to implement a message system using mysql for storage.

This is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `message` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_from` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_to` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `message` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

id_from is the msg sender, id_to is the msg receiver .

Below inserting 4 messages for testing purposes:

```
INSERT INTO `message`(`id`,`id_from`,`id_to`,`time`,`message`) VALUES
(1,1,2,'2012-07-05 12:18:49','msg1'),
(2,2,1,'2012-07-05 12:18:58','msg2'),
(3,3,1,'2012-07-05 12:19:04','msg3'),
(4,1,3,'2012-07-05 12:19:10','msg4');
```

What I want to do and not succeeding, is building a query that fetches the last sent or received message for each pair (id_from, id_to) for a specific user.
In this case, the result would be:

```
row1: 2,2,1,'2012-07-05 12:18:58','msg2'
row2: 4,1,3,'2012-07-05 12:19:10','msg4'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT id, id_from, id_to, time, message
FROM (  SELECT 
        FROM message
        WHERE 1 IN (id_from, id_to) # 1 is user_id in this case
        ORDER BY time DESC) AS h
GROUP BY LEAST(id_from, id_to), GREATEST(id_from, id_to)
```

**Solution for gaining the last sent and received message** (not what's asked for though)

```
SELECT id, id_from, id_to, time, message
FROM (  SELECT 
        FROM message
        WHERE 1 IN (id_from, id_to) # 1 is user_id in this case
        ORDER BY time DESC) AS h
GROUP BY id_from, id_to
```

Should do it I guess.

I'm sure there are "prettier" format to capture this in.

Consider:

```
SELECT id, 'from' AS type, id_from AS type_id, time, message
FROM message
WHERE id_to = 1
ORDER BY time DESC
LIMIT 1
UNION ALL
SELECT id, 'to', id_to, time, message
FROM message
WHERE id_from = 1
ORDER BY time DESC
LIMIT 1
```

This would give you:

```
id  type  type_id  time                 message
3   from  3        2012-07-05 12:19:04  msg3
4   to    3        2012-07-05 12:19:10  msg4
```

Comment: i checked, it's not showing right, it returned row id3 and id4

Comment: That's what's it's supposed to do, right? id3 got later time than id2. Or you want the latest message of every conversation?

Comment: i checked the last query, it does the same thing... :(

Comment: Yes. Try the newest one in the top. Might be what you're after.

Comment: Thanks, it worked like a charm. English is not my native language, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You're welcome. Had you explained that you wanted the last message in each conversation for a certain user, I would've understood what you meant earlier :)

Comment: Could this result be acomplished without a subquery?

Comment: In theory, yes. It would however require a big JOIN statement instead, which I can't at the moment figure out how to create. Why?

Comment: i would like to create a view but mysql doesn't support subquery in FROM clause.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM messages WHERE id_from = 1 OR id_to = 1 ?

Comment: that would get all the messages from the db for that user, i only want the last message for each user that talked with user1